# Máscara redonda em imagem com CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Efeito]

[image: imagem original]
*imagem original*

Gostaria de saber como colocar o fundo cinza e cortar a parte de fora do jogador pra ficar apenas dentro do círculo.

Comment: Desde que a imagem tenha o fundo transparente é só usar o `background-color` e o `border-radius`. O border radius arredonda as bordas, então é só alterar até ficar um circulo como você deseja, e o fundo cinza é só fazer com o background color. Você poder usar o `rgba` para definir uma transparencia caso deseje que o cinza seja transparente.

Answer (score 9):

pode-se criar uma img dentro de uma div com "overflow:hidden;"

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/atUuf.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Tomás, você pode melhorar o resultado adicionando `transform: scale(1.4)` em `.circle img`.

Comment: isso depende da imagem

Answer (score 7):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```css
img{
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 200px;  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/atUuf.png" alt="" />
```

Isso para teste, em desenvolvimento colocaria uma classe ou ID, acho mais simples assim.

Answer (score 2):

CSS - basta aplicar uma class em um botão com a imagem como fundo, porém é aconselhável aplicar uma borda.

```css
.tim{
    border: 2px solid #AD235E;
    border-radius: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 190px; background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/atUuf.png);
    background-position: center;
    }
```

```html
<button class="tim">
    </button>
```

Pode ser uma div também, só colocar a cor do fundo no CSS

```css
.tim{
    //border: 2px solid #AD235E;
    border-radius: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 190px; background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/atUuf.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="tim">
    </div>
```

Comment: O fundo ficou cinza por ter utilizado `button`? Um cuidado que deve ser tomado ao utilizar o `button` é na acessibilidade, pois, por padrão, um botão possui `tabindex = 0` e é adicionado à lista de navegação por Tab. Sendo apenas uma imagem talvez isso não seja interessante.

Comment: Pode ser uma div também, só colocar a cor do fundo